# Filter search Results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a code that searches items from a search bar, however it is on a select dropdown with the search:

[[image: Select Filter]]

However I reciently decided i did not want the select and only the query filter, how would I seperate the code? From the select to independent search. Here is the code I used:

## Javascript:

```
// AngularJS

var phonecatApp = angular.module('app', []);

phonecatApp.controller('ListCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
        'name': 'Item 1'
    }, {
        'name': 'Item 2'
    }, {
        'name': 'Account 3'
    }, {
        'name': 'Account 4'
    }, {
        'name': 'Item 5'
    }, {
        'name': 'Item 6'
    }, {
        'name': 'User 7'
    }, {
        'name': 'User 8'
    }, {
        'name': 'Item 9'
    }, {
        'name': 'Item 10'
    }, {
        'name': 'Item 11'
    }, {
        'name': 'Item 12'
    }, {
        'name': 'Item 13'
    }, {
        'name': 'Item 14'
    }, {
        'name': 'User 15'
    }, {
        'name': 'User 16'
    }, {
        'name': 'Person 17'
    }, {
        'name': 'Person 18'
    }, {
        'name': 'Person 19'
    }, {
        'name': 'Item 20'
    }, ];
});

// jQuery
$('.dropdown-menu').find('input').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

## HTML:

```
 <div class="dropdown dropdown-scroll" ng-app="app">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Select <span class="caret">    </span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" ng-controller="ListCtrl">
        <li role="presentation">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm search-control"> <span   class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Query" ng-model="query"></input>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation" ng-repeat='item in items | filter:query'>     <a href="#"> {{item.name}} </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

## CSS:

```
.dropdown.dropdown-scroll .dropdown-menu {
    max-height: 200px;
    width: 60px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.search-control {
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kyrcha/ULSy3/6/)

Comment: Are you open to use add on library? Because what you need is Typehead, and Angular UI Bootstrap has perfect directive for it. 
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#typeahead

Comment: I am only if all else fails

Comment: @Shantanu if you want to put in answer ill accept and upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have just input field on the vie initially then on query edit you show the filtered options to user & when user selects the option you can hide all the options. So this way it'll appear & work just like Typehead. So you can change your template to as follows:

```
<div class="body-container" ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm search-control"> 
      <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Query" 
        ng-model="query" ng-change="queryUpdated()" />
    </div>
    <div class="items" ng-hide="isSelected">
      <p class="search-items" ng-click="selectItem(item.name)" 
       ng-repeat='item in items | filter:query track by $index'> {{item.name}}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then along with your existing controller code add these two functions:

```
$scope.selectItem = function(selected) {
    $scope.query = selected;
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.isSelected = true;
    });
}
$scope.queryUpdated = function() {
    $scope.isSelected = false;
}
```

So this way you can have Typehead like feature & also you can change its behavior according to requirement like showing list on first load or when user unaware of options at all.

[**Working jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/shantanu_k/qLwjxv44/)

Now you can implement same thing using Angular UI Bootstrap plugin library. With that your code will look

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" 
uib-typeahead="item.name for item in items | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" 
class="form-control">
```

Here uib-typehead directive from library will handle addition of template for dropdown options & handling its animation using ngAnimate.

[**Working plunker Example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/y9xznyZpQMi50jfrJg5r?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you! I have been trying this for days!